# Download XML file with Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I've created an `ActionResult` in an `MVC` controller which returns a `FileStreamResult` of an `XMLfile`, but it's not downloading the file. 
After the action returns the `FileStream` nothing happens; I'd like to make the user download the file from the web application.

Any help? 
Thanks

```
public ActionResult EsportaProtocollo(int idProtocollo)
{
    AvvisoModel avviso = new AvvisoModel();

    string xml = _protocolliService.ProtocolloToXml(idProtocollo);

    var newStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(newStream);
    writer.Write(xml);
    writer.Flush();
    newStream.Position = 0;

    return File(newStream, "application/xml", "prova.xml");

}
```

Here's what I see on Fiddler

[image: Here's what I see on Fiddler.]

Comment: Give us your code, pls.

Comment: Put part of code to understand where you stuck.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "its not downloading the file"? What *is* happening? Have you looked at what's happening at an HTTP level, e.g. with Fiddler2?

Comment: can we see part of your javascript, where your call this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! the problem was the javascript, i was calling the action with an ajax call, i've changed it to a window.open(url); and now it works!